# Unit testing an endpoint with @RequestBody

Tags: java, junit, mockito

So I am getting a 400 for my HTTP response code when it should be 200. I am passing in a byte[] object to the endpoint but it doesn't seem to be adding the content-type correctly? Any suggestions?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/octet-stream")
      public ResponseEntity<String> receiveCompressedBinary(@RequestHeader String site, @RequestHeader String customer,
          @RequestHeader String table, @RequestBody byte[] binary, @RequestHeader String loadStatus) {
        if(binary.length < maxFileSize) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else{
          return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE);
        }
      }
```

My test:

```
@Test
  public void testUploadCompressedBinaryInitialRunning() throws Exception{
    File file = new File("src/test/resources/testFile.txt");
    String site = "site";
    String customer = "customer";
    String table = "table";
    String loadStatus = "INITIALRUNNING";
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/test").header("site",site).param("customer",customer).
        param("table", table).content(compress(file)).param("loadStatus",loadStatus)
        .with(user("user"))).andExpect(status().isOk());
   this.mockMvc.perform(post("/uploadCompressedBinary")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
```

Compress method:

```
 public static byte[] compress(File file) throws IOException {
    if (file.length() == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    byte[] fileInBytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    try {
      //convert file into array of bytes
      fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
      fileInputStream.read(fileInBytes);
      fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Exception whilst compressing the file: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream obj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
    gzip.write(fileInBytes);
    gzip.close();
    return obj.toByteArray();
  }
```

UPDATE: Got past it, rather than .param, I should be using .header

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you are setting the content type when you are posting.

Try

```
this.mockMvc.perform(post("/test").header("site",site).param("customer",customer).
        param("table", table).content(compress(file)).contentType("application/octet-stream").param("loadStatus",loadStatus)
        .with(user("user"))).andExpect(status().isOk());
```